# Wi-fi network completely disables when I close lid (suspend)

Tags: wifi, networking

My wi-fi completely disables not allowing me to enable it again (see photo) [image]

when I close the lid of my laptop. I found a post regarding the same issue but the solution posted there did not work for me. The solution was to run 'sudo service network-manager restart' but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was using the function network button (on/off) and the funny thing is that it does not disable the network anymore when I suspend the laptop when closing the lid! computers work in mysterious ways... (sometimes)